# Component: Update `Items` from `TComboBox`

Tags: delphi, components, items

I have an own component derived from `TWinControl` which contain inside more standard components (e.g. `TEdit`, `TCombobox`). This sub-components are not published, therefore their properties are not visible.

But some of them I would like to make them visible, but under my component.
I succeed to handle some properties like `Text`, `Enabled`,`ReadOnly`, but now I would like to add also `Items` from `TComboBox`.

This mean, after I edit my own `Items` property, same should happen with `Items` from `TCombo` sub-component.

```
[ComponentPlatformsAttribute(pidWin32 or pidWin64)]
  TSodaEditor = class(TWinControl)
  private
    FEdit: TEdit;
    FCombo: TComboBox;
    FAlignment: TAlignment;
    FItems: TStrings; //<-------
    FText: TCaption;
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnEnter: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnExit: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnClick: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnDblClick: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnKeyDown: TEvent_OnKeyDown;
    FOnKeyUp: TEvent_OnKeyUp;
    FOnKeyPress: TEvent_OnKeyPress;
    //....
  protected
    //....
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
 published
    property Alignment: TAlignment read FAlignment write SetAlignment default taLeftJustify;
    property ReadOnly: Boolean read FReadOnly write SetReadOnly default False;
    property Items: TStrings read FItems write SetItems;
    property Text;
    property Visible;
    property Enabled;
    property Align;
    property Font;
    property ParentFont;
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
    property OnKeyDown;
    property OnKeyPress;
    property OnKeyUp;
    property OnExit;
    property OnEnter;
    property OnClick;
    property OnDblClick;
    property TabOrder;
  end;
```

Any easy way or should I override some methods from `TStrings` in order to catch the changes made under `Items`?

**Update:**
Via this `Items` I would like to handle also objects by using `AddObject`. So when I select an item from `TCombo` sub-component I would like to get the object assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply expose *direct* access to the `TComboBox.Items` from your own `Items` getter/setter. No need for the `FItems` member at all.

```
property Items: TStrings read GetItems write SetItems;

function TSodaEditor.GetItems: TStrings;
begin
  Result := FCombo.Items;
end;

procedure TSodaEditor.SetItems(AValue: TStrings);
begin
  FCombo.Items.Assign(AValue);
end;
```